# How to hide overlay when using Confirm dialog and set its position in PrimeNG?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm working with a **Dialog window** and **Confirm dialog**. When I first get the dialog window the overlay gets display (This is expected), but when I click on the **OPEN CHART** button I get the Confirm dialog but its overlay is all over (meaning that I can't do anything on the page anymore), so my questions are:

1) How to **hide** the overlay of the **Confirm Dialog** so that I can click on either yes or not buttons?

2) How to set the position of the Confirm Dialog? I've been using **positionTop** and **positionLet** for the Dialog and it works great!, but I cant get it to work with the **Confirm Dialog**. I simply want the Confirm dialog to go over the Dialog window.

**NOTE:** In order to see the Dialog window just click on any row of my table.

Here's my working code:
[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0uD6wlaZNwpq0LrSWn7s?p=preview)

```
<p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="330"></p-confirmDialog>

<button type="text" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="fa-check" label="OPEN CHART"></button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me... I moved the p-confirmDialog outside the p-dialog

```
<p-dialog appendTo = "body" header="Title" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" width="350" height="300" positionLeft="{{positionLeft}}" positionTop="{{positionTop}}">
  {{personData}}
    <button type="text" (click)="confirm()" pButton icon="fa-check" label="OPEN CHART"></button>
</p-dialog>
     <p-confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="330"></p-confirmDialog>

<p-dataTable [value]="data" resizableColumns="true" selectionMode="single" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)">
  <p-column field="status" header="Name" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="name" header="Email" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Comment: @jriver27 Do you know how to make Confirm Dialog go over my Dialog and NOT show up in the middle of the page? as you can see I'm using positionLeft and positionTop to set the position on DIalog, but I get it to work with the Confirm Dialog

Comment: @HenryDev For that you would have to do some custom scripting the get the exact location of the user's click. OR Make the dialog appear in the center of the screen. Good luck! Also If my answer helped, could you make it the accepted answer. Thanks.